# Return sql query as array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, jquery-ui

I'm using jqueryui and its Autocomplete plugin. It use a json to extract items.

I want to modify it so that items will be extracted from my db.

Here is how items should be :

```
$items = array(
"Great <em>Bittern</em>"=>"Botaurus stellaris",
"Great2 <em>Bittern</em>"=>"Botaurus stellaris 2"
);
```

How to make an sql query that extract data from a table and write it like the code above into the php file ?

```
Table : customer
id_customer | name_customer | country_customer
```

I want that array produce `id_customer => name_customer`

Comment: To give you the exact code, we would need to know what your database schemas looks like. What are your field names?

Comment: It seems that i made an error with posting a new message in place of a comment.

Anyway, message above edited (thanks for admin by the way :) )

Comment: Do your id's have HTML formatting (`<em>`) on them? You shouldn't have that on that DB.

Comment: No, it's just an exemple extracted from the jquerui docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query is just:

```
SELECT id_customer, name_customer FROM customer
```

and you can generate the array like so (*assuming you are using MySQL*):

```
$items = array();

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $items[$row['id_customer']] = $row['name_customer'];
}
```

**References:** [MySQL `SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   //Use mysql_connect for connect to a Db

   $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
   if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

   // Select a DB
   $db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $link);
   if (!$db_selected) {
      die ('Can\'t use dbame_n : ' . mysql_error());
   }

   //Build a query
   $sql = "SELECT id_customer, name_customer FROM customer";

   //Send de query to db  
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   // Initialize Array
   $arr_customers = array();
   while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
       $arr_customers[$row['id_customer']] = $row['name_customer'];
   }

   // convert to JSON
   $json = json_encode($arr_customers);

   // Send to JqueryUI

   echo $json;
   exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: I wonder what would JqueryUI do with all these `'Could not connect: '` if happens