# PHP looping results into array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to save SQL query results into array:

This loop only produces 1 result in array:

```
<?php

$term = $_GET['term'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM Bob WHERE h_city LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY 
h_city ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result = $row['h_city'];
        array_push($result);
    }
    $json = json_encode(array($result));
    echo $json;
    ?>
```

result is: ["example1"]
How to save query into array like ["example1","example2"]. Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong, or anyone can point me to the right direction?

**EDIT**
as it was mentioned in the comments this way of doing queries is prone to SQL injections:
[more info here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
more info on converting results to arrays:
[more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384292/return-sql-query-as-array)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: `array_push($result);` makes little sense. You need to supply at least two parameters, starting with the second one, those are the values you actually want to push into the array.

Comment: `$result` is your query result then on first loop iteration you destroy it `$result = $row['h_city'];`

Comment: `$result` is already being used as the resource for your query, and you're overwriting `$result`. The array push is just wrong here.

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting, **NOW!** PHP would have already told you about this (“Warning: array_push() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in […]”). It should really not be necssary that _we_ alert you to this kind of mistake/inattention, when PHP by itself can do that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple code change will do you well here, just put all of the row info in an array called items (or any other name that makes sense).

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $items[] = $row['h_city']; // add to an array called items
}
$json = json_encode($items);
echo $json;
```

I think likely your query is wrong too because you are limiting the list of cities here:

```
WHERE h_city LIKE '%".$term."%'
```

Which should only return a match for a single city.

**WARNING** You should listen to those who provided a critique of your code in the comments under your question. You made a lot of fundamental mistakes that you could likely have solved yourself if you had error reporting on and visible.

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!